# Pass information from one web service to another web service in the same data-view-web-part

Tags: data-view-web-part

In Data View Web Part.

Is it possible to pass information from one web Service data source connection to another web service data source connection within the same Data Form Web Part to get information from second web service?

What I am trying to achieve is to get user email address from the User Profile Web Service and pass in to another web service to get information.

Please advise if it is possible.

Thanks,
Nithin

Answer (score 1):

I tried the SPSerives route on the master page that for some reason did not work for me. I took the server side approach wrote a custom control to get it working. Deployed the custom control project replaced  with the new tag for the custom control  within the SelectParameter in Data source String in the .webpart file. This way I got the user profile information pass to the web service.

It would be great to use the client side though.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to wire this up with DVWPs but take a look at my open source SPServices jQuery library. It might make it easier. http://spservices.codeplex.com

Comment: I am using jquery.SPServices-0.3.1.js and below is the code, however when I kept a watch on thisUserAccount and thisEmail on firebug they are returning the same values "domain\enterpriseID" that I use for loggin to the site. <script type="text/javascript" src="../Style Library/jquery.SPServices-0.3.1.js"></script>  <script type="text/javascript">  var thisUserAccount = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "Name", debug: false }); var thisEmail = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "EMail", debug: false }); </script>

other static names retured the same value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also,

_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True

Checked that, There are values populated for Account, Name, Email, SIP Address, Job Title.

Comment: I assume that you mean a different version of SPServices, as the current version is 0.5.6. SPGetCurrentUser is always going to return values for the current user, of course.

Comment: What I meant to say was I used jquery.SPServices-0.3.1 and for

var thisEmail = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "EMail", debug: false }); It returned me AccountName and not Email. So the problem is that I am not getting the email eventhough I use EMail as the fieldName in the fuction.

Comment: Also when I use the currrent version 0.5.6 I get this error


a script on this page may be busy or it may have stopped responding. you can stop the script now

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. Can you put your code in your initial post above?